# SUSE Linux Enterprise 12: Change Hostname permanently

Tags: linux, command-line, vmware, hostname, suse

I want to change the hostname for a VM, but struggle to do it permanently. Already changed it via `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname`, but did't work out. Does anyone have an advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: do a reboot, then try again

Answer (score 3):

Since SLES 12 should be running systemd, use:

```
hostnamectl set-hostname <hostname>
```